# Convert Planet Imagery Surface Reflectance product DN to surface reflectance values

Tags: remote-sensing, atmospheric-correction, planet, reflectance

I have a PlanetScope Ortho Scene Product (3B) which includes an AnalyticMS.tif and AnalyticMS_SR.tif files. Based on what I have read so far, the AnalyticMS_SR.tif file is scaled surface reflectance in Digital Number. How do I convert the DN to surface reflectance value?

I have read that for AnalyticMS.tif, I can convert the DNs into TOA reflectance or radiance by multiplying them with the given reflectance coefficient or radiometric scale factor. Is there something like that for the the Surface Reflectance product?

Comment: @ StarterPack Did you figure out how to process the image? I also have *20190722_155754_1049_3B_AnalyticMS image and I need to get the surface reflectance. Can you please help me? I am new to remote sensing and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The SR product is provided as a 16-bit GeoTIFF image with reflectance values scaled by 10,000.

There is also a tutorial  [tutorial](https://developers.planet.com/tutorials/convert-planetscope-imagery-from-radiance-to-reflectance/) to convert MS radiance to reflectance.

Comment: +1 You are correct. From the documentation that your provided, Planet states the following: "The four coefficients a,b,c,d are calculated and provided with every analytic image that Planet provides and can be used as simple scaling factors to convert from radiance to reflectance."